# Subtracting two sums

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum

Please suppose this [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cb7e1e432c6f02d6f3a959a7e9d0aeed).

```
-- INVENTORY TABLE DECLARATION AND DATA INSERTION
DECLARE @COLORSIZEQTYS TABLE(ITEID int, COLORCODE varchar(15), QTYMODE smallint, SIZE4 float, SIZE5 float, SIZE6 float, SIZE7 float);

INSERT @COLORSIZEQTYS(ITEID, COLORCODE, QTYMODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(5594, 'Grey',  1, -2, -1,  3,  4);
INSERT @COLORSIZEQTYS(ITEID, COLORCODE, QTYMODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(5594, 'Red',   1,  2,  5,  5,  2);
INSERT @COLORSIZEQTYS(ITEID, COLORCODE, QTYMODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(5594, 'Green', 1,  2,  2,  4, -1);
INSERT @COLORSIZEQTYS(ITEID, COLORCODE, QTYMODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(5594, 'Grey',  0,  2,  0, -1,  1);
INSERT @COLORSIZEQTYS(ITEID, COLORCODE, QTYMODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(5594, 'White', 0,  2,  3,  3,  0);
INSERT @COLORSIZEQTYS(ITEID, COLORCODE, QTYMODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(5594, 'Blue',  1, -1,  6,  0,  3);
INSERT @COLORSIZEQTYS(ITEID, COLORCODE, QTYMODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(5594, 'Grey',  1,  7,  2, -1,  4);
INSERT @COLORSIZEQTYS(ITEID, COLORCODE, QTYMODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(5594, 'Grey',  1,  1,  0, -1, -1);

-- PURCHASES TABLE DECLARATION AND DATA INSERTION
DECLARE @STORECOLORSIZEEST TABLE(ID int, ITEID int, COLORCODE varchar(15), SIZE4 float, SIZE5 float, SIZE6 float, SIZE7 float);

INSERT @STORECOLORSIZEEST(ID, ITEID, COLORCODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(1703, 5594, 'Grey', 0, 1, 0, 1);
INSERT @STORECOLORSIZEEST(ID, ITEID, COLORCODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(1704, 6811, 'Red',  0, 1, 0, 1);
INSERT @STORECOLORSIZEEST(ID, ITEID, COLORCODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(1706, 5594, 'Grey', 0, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT @STORECOLORSIZEEST(ID, ITEID, COLORCODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(1707, 5594, 'Grey', 1, 1, 0, 1);
INSERT @STORECOLORSIZEEST(ID, ITEID, COLORCODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(1709, 8372, 'Blue', 0, 1, 0, 1);
INSERT @STORECOLORSIZEEST(ID, ITEID, COLORCODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7) VALUES(1712, 5594, 'Grey', 0, 0, 1, 1);

-- QUERY SUMMING INVENTORY ROWS
SELECT SUM(SIZE4) AS QTY4,
       SUM(SIZE5) AS QTY5,
       SUM(SIZE6) AS QTY6,
       SUM(SIZE7) AS QTY7
FROM @COLORSIZEQTYS
WHERE ITEID = 5594
AND COLORCODE = 'Grey'
AND QTYMODE = 1

-- QUERY SUMMING INVENTORY ROWS AND ZERO-ING NEGATIVE VALUES
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SIZE4 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE SIZE4 END) AS QTY4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SIZE5 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE SIZE5 END) AS QTY5,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SIZE6 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE SIZE6 END) AS QTY6,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SIZE7 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE SIZE7 END) AS QTY7
FROM @COLORSIZEQTYS
WHERE ITEID = 5594
AND COLORCODE = 'Grey'
AND QTYMODE = 1

-- QUERY SUMMING PURCHASE ROWS
SELECT SUM(SIZE4) AS RSV4,
       SUM(SIZE5) AS RSV5,
       SUM(SIZE6) AS RSV6,
       SUM(SIZE7) AS RSV7
FROM @STORECOLORSIZEEST
WHERE ITEID = 5594
AND COLORCODE = 'Grey'

-- SUBTRACTING THE TWO SUMS TO FIND THE FINAL INVENTORY QUANTITIES - CLEARLY THIS DOESN'T WORK
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN inv.SIZE4 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE inv.SIZE4 END) - SUM(pcs.SIZE4)) AS TOT4,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN inv.SIZE5 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE inv.SIZE5 END) - SUM(pcs.SIZE5)) AS TOT5,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN inv.SIZE6 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE inv.SIZE6 END) - SUM(pcs.SIZE6)) AS TOT6,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN inv.SIZE7 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE inv.SIZE7 END) - SUM(pcs.SIZE7)) AS TOT7
FROM @COLORSIZEQTYS AS inv
INNER JOIN @STORECOLORSIZEEST AS pcs ON pcs.ITEID = inv.ITEID AND pcs.COLORCODE = inv.COLORCODE
WHERE inv.ITEID = 5594 AND inv.COLORCODE = 'Grey' AND inv.QTYMODE = 1
```

So I have two tables, one is an inventory of products with their quantities for each size, and the other is purchase lines of products with the purchased quantities of each size.

I want to calculate the final new inventory quantities of each size, zero-ing the over-sold sizes (this over-selling happens some times because the operator of the system fails to register some sales).

Anyway, for the fiddle's example, the totals should literally be like

| TOT4 | TOT5 | TOT6 | TOT7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | -1 | 1 | 4 |

and after we zero the over-sold ones, they should become

| TOT4 | TOT5 | TOT6 | TOT7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 4 |

In my fiddle I've attempted to calculate the subtraction of the two sums, but I don't know what I've dome wrong, as it calculates totally different results! I know I'm close, but I can't make it work.

Can someone correct the final query for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

The error in your query is that all of the relevant individual purchase rows are joining onto all of the relevant individual inventory rows, where by "relevant" I mean the grey 5594's. The easiest way to understand what I mean by that would be to run your final query, but do a select * instead of taking the sums.

The solution is to make sure you take the sums first, then join the purchase results onto the inventory results, and then do the subtraction (instead of joining before summing).

When we do this we can cross join, because after we filter to the colour and item we want and take the sums, there will only be a single row for the purchases, and a single row for the inventory.

For the sake of simplicity I have removed the example data that has no bearing on the query.

Also, I have included an entire setup and solution, because I think you might learn a couple of things from that, too. Notice, for example, that you don't have to do separate insert statements for every values row. You can just add a comma after each inserted row. This makes the setup much easier to read.

```sql
-- INVENTORY TABLE DECLARATION AND DATA INSERTION
declare @COLORSIZEQTYS TABLE
(
   ITEID     int,
   COLORCODE varchar(15),
   QTYMODE   smallint,
   SIZE4     float,
   SIZE5     float,
   SIZE6     float,
   SIZE7     float
);

-- PURCHASES TABLE DECLARATION AND DATA INSERTION
declare @STORECOLORSIZEEST TABLE
(
   ID        int,
   ITEID     int,
   COLORCODE varchar(15),
   SIZE4     float,
   SIZE5     float,
   SIZE6     float,
   SIZE7     float
);

insert @COLORSIZEQTYS(ITEID, COLORCODE, QTYMODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7)
values
(5594, 'Grey', 1,     -2, -1, 3, 4),
(5594, 'Grey', 0,     2, 0, -1, 1),
(5594, 'Grey', 1,     7, 2, -1, 4),
(5594, 'Grey', 1,     1, 0, -1, -1);

insert @STORECOLORSIZEEST(ID, ITEID, COLORCODE, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7)
values
(1703, 5594, 'Grey',  0, 1, 0, 1),
(1706, 5594, 'Grey',  0, 1, 1, 1),
(1707, 5594, 'Grey',  1, 1, 0, 1),
(1712, 5594, 'Grey',  0, 0, 1, 1);

with zeroedinv as
(
   select   SUM(case when SIZE4 < 0 then 0 else SIZE4 end) as QTY4,
            SUM(case when SIZE5 < 0 then 0 else SIZE5 end) as QTY5,
            SUM(case when SIZE6 < 0 then 0 else SIZE6 end) as QTY6,
            SUM(case when SIZE7 < 0 then 0 else SIZE7 end) as QTY7
   from     @COLORSIZEQTYS
   where    ITEID = 5594
            and COLORCODE = 'Grey'
            and QTYMODE = 1
),
purchases as
(
   select   SUM(SIZE4) as RSV4,
            SUM(SIZE5) as RSV5,
            SUM(SIZE6) as RSV6,
            SUM(SIZE7) as RSV7
   from     @STORECOLORSIZEEST
   where    ITEID = 5594
            and COLORCODE = 'Grey'
)
select      totl4 = iif(qty4 - rsv4 < 0, 0, qty4 - rsv4),
            totl5 = iif(qty5 - rsv5 < 0, 0, qty5 - rsv5),
            totl6 = iif(qty6 - rsv6 < 0, 0, qty6 - rsv6),
            totl7 = iif(qty7 - rsv7 < 0, 0, qty7 - rsv7)
from        zeroedinv   
cross join  purchases
```

Comment: I get this error:

> Msg 319 Level 15 State 1 Line 53
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
> Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 63
> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Additionally, is there any other approach to solve my problem? Without using the WITH clause! TIA

Comment: @FayeD. Did you copy my code exactly? Make sure you have the semicolon after the last `values` row inserted into `@STORECOLORSIZEEST`. If you don't want to use CTEs you can just copy the exact CTE selects and add them as two subqueries: `select ... from ( select ...) t1 cross join (select ...) t2`