# ORDER results based on a custom order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table of 5000+ products. One column holds the size of the products (clothes, shoes etc) and I need to add two levels of `ORDER`ing. At first by product name, and then by size (so that they get imported in another app later in the correct order)...

I've set up a small fiddle for you [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3fdce3094cb31ceb8cb96834b90b5020) where I've tried to include as many different cases as possible

The problem is that the size values are mixed, depending on the product... There are:

- numeric values (43, 40.5, 42 1/3, 38 1/2)
- character sizes (XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, 2XL, XXXL, 3XL)
- ranges (4-6, 7-8, 32-34, 38-42),
- textual sizes (Size Three, Size Five, No Size)

From all those, the most obvious are the numeric values, but even for those, I'm worrying that `ORDER BY` will get confused when it'll have to sort, let's say, 40.5 and 41 1/2, or in other words when it'll have to sort decimals along with mixed fractions etc

EDIT: Indeed it sorts numbers as text, sorting `28 1/2` fraction before `28 1/3` and also decimal size `28.5` at the end of any size starting with 28...

Things will get even more complex when it'll have to sort character sizes where it'll have to sort XXS, before XS, then S, etc...

I'm not sure how it'll manage to sort ranges either...

All in all, it seems like a very tedious or even near to impossible job for SQL...

One solution I thought was to craft a temporary mixed table at least for character sizes and textual sizes, where I'll define the correct order, and so SQL will sort (if that's even possible) my products according to that reference table. The problem is I can't include in that table numeric sizes, as they are so so many... I mean, to be foolproof for the future, I'll have to include all decimals up to, let's say, 54, and usual mixed fractions of them (n 1/3, n 1/2, n 2/3)...

From what I've seen the unique values currently used by the products are the following:

```
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
14
16
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
50
52
54
116
128
140
152
164
S
M
L
XL
XXL
47.5
48 1/2
42 1/2
44 1/2
29.5
31.5
33.5
19.5
23.5
42.5
XS
One Size
35.5
37.5
44.5
45.5
40 2/3
44 2/3
43 1/3
47 1/3
46 2/3
42 2/3
41 1/3
45 1/3
38.5
39 1/3
31-35
34-38
38-42
42-46
46-50
2XL
37 1/3
36 2/3
26.5
21.5
27.5
32.5
22.5
48.5
28.5
40.5
30.5
39.5
41.5
36.5
23 1/2
38 2/3
37-39
34-36
43-45
31-33
40-42
27-30
35 1/2
18.5
3XL
35-38
39-42
43-46
Size Seven
24.5
Size Five
47-49
3-6
6-9
2-6
8-9
6-7
10-11
14-15
12-13
46.5
4XL
XXS
156-166
33 1/2
30 1/2
31 1/2
28 1/2
XXXL
No Size
46-48
L-XL
S-M
49 1/3
40 1/2
34.5
4-5
2-3
13-14
9-10
11-12
7-8
```

Can you please guide me to the correct direction for dealing with this?

**EDIT:**

I made a deep analysis on the sizes, checking all active sizelists one by one, and after deleting duplicates etc, I ended up to:

► These 5 groups, which I hand-sorted:

```
XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, 2XL, XXXL, 3XL, XXXXL, 4XL, 
S-M, L-XL, 
No Size, One Size, Size Five, Size Seven, 
25'', 27'', 
0-1, 0-3, 1-2, 2-3, 2-6, 3-4, 3-6, 4-5, 5-6, 6-7, 6-9, 6-14, 7-8, 8-9, 9-10, 9-12, 10-11, 11-12, 12-13, 12-18, 13-14, 14-15, 15-16, 16-17, 17-18, 27-30, 31-33, 31-35, 34-36, 34-38, 35-38, 37-39, 38-42, 39-42, 40-42, 42-46, 43-45, 43-46, 46-48, 46-50, 47-49, 47-50, 146-156, 156-166,
```

► A bunch of numeric sizes which I think can be handled pretty well my SQL (PHP sorted them fine)

So I'm thinking about creating a reference table through which I'll sort any non-numeric sizes, and then somehow cast the rest of the numeric sizes to numbers and sort them accordingly.

But how could I implement all this theoretical scenario?

**EDIT2:**

I tried and `ISNUMERIC(28 1/2)` doesn't even return `1` so that makes it even harder...

Comment: Assuming a given product only has 1 of the 4 size options, you need to specify how that translates into an ordering and then write the SQL to transform it. If the database is designed correctly, then the size options will be stored in another table, and you could add an `OrderBy` column to the size table which is numeric and easy to sort on.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, the same product only has sizes of the same type of sizes.

Comment: The DB isn't very well designed, plus I have absolutely no control over it. It's from an older merchant desktop app that I'm building a bridge for an e-comm website... I can only run `SELECT` queries to grab the products I need... The final query of my job can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384737/15576971 and all that's left is to do the sorting I'm describing here!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the constraints you have indicated i.e. no ability to control the database structure, then I suggest hardcoding a mapping table similar to the following. You would normally store this in the database, as part of the table where the size information is stored. This will fail should a new size be added but not much you can do about that. Another option is to try and use a rules based approach where you try and compute this based on knowing the pattern of the sizes, but I expect that will be more work than benefit in this case.

```
declare @MyTable table ([Name] varchar(32), Size varchar(32));

insert into @MyTable ([Name], Size)
values
('Shirt','XS'),
('Shirt','XL'),
('Dress','7-8'),
('Dress','38-42');

select *
from @MyTable T
left join (
  values
  ('XXS', 1), ('XS', 2), ('S', 3), ('M', 4), ('L', 5), ('XL', 6), ('XXL', 7), ('2XL', 8), ('XXXL', 9), ('3XL', 10)
  , ('4-6', 1), ('7-8', 2), ('32-34', 3), ('38-42', 4)
) S1 (Size, OrderBy) on S1.Size = T.Size
order by T.[Name], S1.OrderBy;
```

Comment: DaleK could you please read my edited question, focusing on the EDITed part, and give me a hint on this scenario?

Comment: @FayeD. its not OK to fundamentally change a question once an answer has been provided. You need to ask a new question.